# Cassandra unit-test Spring boot : cassandra.jmx.local.port missing from cassandra-env.sh,

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

When trying to run Cassandra unit-test with spring boot/data i got this error.

Full stack:

```
  10:31:15.058 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.cassandra.service.StartupChecks - cassandra.jmx.local.port missing from cassandra-env.sh, unable to start local JMX service.

10:16:09.001 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

This is the sql script:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS todo (id TimeUUID PRIMARY KEY, title text);
CREATE INDEX titleindex ON todo (title);

and this is my class:

```
 @PrimaryKey
    private UUID id;

    private String title;
```

And this is the test class:

```
   @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(mergeMode = MergeMode.MERGE_WITH_DEFAULTS, listeners = {OrderedCassandraTestExecutionListener.class })
@SpringBootTest
@CassandraDataSet(keyspace = "todoapp", value = "setup.cql")
@EmbeddedCassandra(timeout = 60000)
public class TodoAppApplicationTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static OutputCapture outputCapture = new OutputCapture();

    @ClassRule
    public static SkipOnWindows skipOnWindows = new SkipOnWindows();

    @Test
    public void testDefaultSettings() throws Exception {
        String output = TodoAppApplicationTest.outputCapture.toString();
        assertThat(output).contains("firstName='Alice'");
    }

    static class SkipOnWindows implements TestRule {

        @Override
        public Statement apply(final Statement base, Description description) {
            return new Statement() {

                @Override
                public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                    if (!runningOnWindows()) {
                        base.evaluate();
                    }
                }

                private boolean runningOnWindows() {
                    return File.separatorChar == '\\';
                }

            };
        }
    }
}
```

I looked in the cassandra-env.sh and i found this configuration:

```
if [ "x$LOCAL_JMX" = "x" ]; then
    LOCAL_JMX=yes
fi
JMX_PORT="7199"

if [ "$LOCAL_JMX" = "yes" ]; then
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=$JMX_PORT"
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
else
  JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.jmx.remote.port=$JMX_PORT"
```

Full stack error:

```
22:34:42.284 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG org.apache.cassandra.service.MigrationManager - Gossiping my schema version 59adb24e-f3cd-3e02-97f0-5b395827453f
Exception (java.lang.NumberFormatException) encountered during startup: For input string: ""
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.getStoragePort(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1052)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.getServerSockets(MessagingService.java:535)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.listen(MessagingService.java:488)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.listen(MessagingService.java:472)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:832)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:727)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:613)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:349)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:551)
    at org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper$1.run(EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.java:125)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
22:34:42.302 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.getStoragePort(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1052)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.getServerSockets(MessagingService.java:535)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.listen(MessagingService.java:488)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.listen(MessagingService.java:472)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:832)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:727)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:613)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:349)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:551)
    at org.cassandraunit.utils.EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper$1.run(EmbeddedCassandraServerHelper.java:125)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
22:34:42.324 [StorageServiceShutdownHook] INFO org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper - Announcing shutdown
22:34:42.324 [StorageServiceShutdownHook] DEBUG org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService - Node /127.0.0.1 state shutdown, token []
22:34:42.330 [PendingRangeCalculator:1] DEBUG org.apache.cassandra.service.PendingRangeCalculatorService - finished calculation for 0 keyspaces in 0ms
22:34:44.333 [StorageServiceShutdownHook] INFO org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService - Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
22:34:44.337 [StorageServiceShutdownHook] INFO org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsService - Paused hints dispatch
22:34:44.340 [StorageServiceShutdownHook] INFO org.apache.cassandra.hints.HintsService - Paused hints dispatch

Process finished with exit code 3
```

Comment: Care to post the full stack trace?

Comment: @mp911de i added the full stack

Comment: You need to fix embedded Cassandra‘s config. The storage port is missing or empty.

Comment: After researching i found this error 

10:31:15.058 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.cassandra.service.StartupChecks - cassandra.jmx.local.port missing from cassandra-env.sh, unable to start local JMX service.

I looked in the cassandra-env.sh and its looks like this

Comment: if [ "x$LOCAL_JMX" = "x" ]; then
    LOCAL_JMX=yes
fi

# Specifies the default port over which Cassandra will be available for
# JMX connections.
# For security reasons, you should not expose this port to the internet.  Firewall it if needed.
JMX_PORT="7199"